# let $R=\{a+b\sqrt -5 :a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ show that $I:= \{a+b\sqrt {-5} :a,b\in \mathbb{Z} , a\equiv b\pmod 2\}$ is maximal ideal of R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

let $R=\{a+b\sqrt {-5} :a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ show that $I:= \{a+b\sqrt {-5} :a,b\in \mathbb{Z} , a\equiv b\pmod 2\}$ is maximal ideal of R , also show that $I= \langle2, 1 +\sqrt{−5} \rangle $

Comment: I would do it in this order: 1) $I$ is an ideal; 2) $I$ contains $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$; 3) $I$ is not the whole ring; 4) $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is maximal because $R/(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is the field ${\mathbb F}_2$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $J$ is an ideal, $I\subsetneq J\subseteq R$. Then $J$ contains an element $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ where either $a$ is odd and $b$ even, or $a$ is even and $b$ odd, i.e. an element of the form
$$(2m+1)+2n\sqrt{-5}$$
or
$$2m+(2n+1)\sqrt{-5}$$
In the first case, $2m+2n\sqrt{-5}\in I$, in the second $(2m+1)+(2n+1)\sqrt{-5}\in I$. Hence, in both cases, $1 =$ $[(2m+1)+2n\sqrt{-5}] - [2m+2n\sqrt{-5}]$ $=$ $[(2m+1)+(2n+1)\sqrt{-5}] - [2m+(2n+1)\sqrt{-5}]$ $\in J$ and so $J$ is the whole of $R$, showing that $I$ is maximal.

As $2\in I$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}\in I$, we have $\langle2,\,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle\subseteq I$. If $a+b\sqrt{-5}\in I$, then $a,b$ are either both odd or both even. Hence, either $a+b\sqrt{-5} = 2m+2n\sqrt{-5}$ $=$ $2(m+n\sqrt{-5})$ $\in\langle2,\,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ or $a+b\sqrt{-5} = (2m+1)+(2n+1)\sqrt{-5}$ $=$ $2(m+n\sqrt{-5})+(1+\sqrt{-5})$ $\in\langle2,\,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$. Hence $I\subseteq\langle2,\,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$. So $I=\langle2,\,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy: show that $R/I$ is a field. First, show that $I = (2,1 + \sqrt{-5})$. Let $a + b\sqrt{-5}\in I$. Then $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$, say $a = b + 2k$. Then $b + 2k + b\sqrt{-5}\in I$, and $b + 2k + b\sqrt{-5} = 2\cdot k + b(1 + \sqrt{-5})$, so $a + b\sqrt{-5}\in (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$, implying $I\subseteq (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$. Conversely, it is easy to see that $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ are both in $I$, so $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})\subseteq I$.

Now, note that $R = \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 + 5)$, and if $I = (2,1 + \sqrt{-5})$, then $R/I = \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 + 5,2,1 + x)$. Then $(x^2 + 5,2,1 + x) = (2,1 + x)$, because $x^2 + 5 - 2\cdot 3 = (1 + x)(x - 1)$. It follows that 
$$
\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2 + 5,2,1 + x)\cong\Bbb F_2[x]/(1 + x)\cong\Bbb F_2,
$$
so $R/I$ is a field and hence $I$ is maximal.